# How to receive carriage return in URL and split on carriage return in php

Tags: php, url

```
url = "http://localhost/reply.php?r=" & Now & "&msg=" & objMessageIn.Body & "&s=" & objMessageIn.Sender

PHP Code:
$ID = rawurlencode($_GET['msg']);
    $SENDER = $_GET['s'];
    $ID_upper = strtoupper($ID);


    print_r($ID_upper);


    $myArray = explode("%0a", $ID_upper);
    print_r($myArray);
```

I want to receive carriage return in URL and split data save in variable.
for example:
In SMS write

```
365 
LES-12-5666
1
2
5
6
```

This SMS receive in GSM device and get in URL in PHP.
When i received in URL, PHP remove the carriage return and show the array i.e
365LES-12-56661256
I want to this type of result

```
array()
{
[0]=>365
[1]=>LES-12-5666
[2]=>1
[3]=>2
[4]=>5
[5]=>6
}
```

I want to split on carriage return. but PHP remove the carriage return so i unable to split this array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post all relevant code within the body of your question. We should be able to paste your code into a text file.  Posting links makes it difficult for us to help you, and the question becomes useless to visitors if the link become invalid in the future. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: what kinds of questions can I ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and Minimal, complete, Verifiable Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Then `edit` your question, so that we may help.

Comment: @SherylHohman thanks I have edited the question

Comment: @SherylHohman I have received msg successfully but not with carriage return. I want to split msg on carriage return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

I've redone my answer and here's the code with explanation to follow:

```
<?php

$url = urlencode("http://www.example.com?r=Now&msg='365\nLES-12-5666\n1\n2\n5\n6\n'&s=&me");

preg_match("/%26msg.+%27/",$url,$matches);

$ID = urldecode( $matches[0]);

$myArray = explode("\\n", $ID);
list(,$str) = explode("=",$myArray[0]);
$str = substr($str,1,-1);
$arr = explode("\n",chop($str));
var_dump($arr);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/GCLXf)

Note: this answer solely focuses on the value of the "msg" portion of the query string.  In real-life perhaps there is a $_GET variable, but in this case it was easier to work with the url as a query string.

The url is urlencoded which allows for the transmission of the newlines which are encoded as "%0A".  The code uses a regex to extract just the "msg" part of the query string.  Then that result is urldecoded which allows the newlines to appear as "\n".  But, in PHP sometimes one must refer to a newline as `"\\n"` as one instance with explode() demonstrates, owing to the string value contained in a single quoted string. A newline in that context is composed of two slashes to represent a slash which escapes "n" so as to stand for the newline character.

$myArray contains one element whose value is the string "msg='365\nLES-12-5666\n1\n2\n5\n6\n'". The code splits the string on the "=" to get the value of "msg" which is actually a single quoted string contained within a string.  The code uses substr() to extract the inner string. To avoid unnecessary empty strings, the code chops off the terminating newline and explodes the string based on the "\n" character into an array $arr.

Comment: In my case, objMessageIn.Body does not have \n or \r. variable is created through trigger after receiving SMS.

url = "http://localhost/reply.php?r=" & Now & "&msg=" & objMessageIn.Body

Comment: @AzharHanif you need to encode the url that gets into PHP.  You can use PHP to do that with urlencode() before it gets into PHP or you can use JavaScript; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent. Certain characters must be encoded if you wish to transmit them via a url and the newline ("\n") is one such character.

Comment: url = "localhost/reply.php?r="; & Now & "&msg=" & objMessageIn.Body

is in vbscript. Can i use server.URLencode function to encode this?

Comment: @Azhar Hanif The last time I worked with vbscript was 1999.  Back then I know that ASP had a way to urlencode a url.  Just now I found this using Google http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042601-1.shtml, so in answer to your question, yes, I believe so.